# Selecting one distinct row from group of entries

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID  TYPE     DATE
1    A    01/02/2019
1    B    01/21/2019
1    C    02/03/2019
2    A    01/04/2019
2    C    01/29/2019
3    A    01/14/2019
3    B    03/11/2019
```

So using the table above as an example what I'm trying to do with a similar table is extract a specific Type from each Distinct ID. So let's say I only want to Select Type B from each Distinct ID. Now, the big confusion starts for me when I incorporate the Date. I want to Select Type B from each ID but only if Type B is the most recent date.

So in this instance the only row with Type B as the last date would be the last row.
`3  B  03/11/2019`

Any suggestions as to what my query should look like?

Comment: The distinct id seems to be irrelevant since you only want the most recent by date? OR are you saying you want as many rows as share the most recent data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.type = 'B'
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and date > t.date
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ozUWyppWGSPCbW8ccwALNB/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | TYPE | DATE                |
| --- | ---- | ------------------- |
| 3   | B    | 2019-03-11 00:00:00 |
```